# Running test coverage separately from test execution

Tags: testing, automated-tests, code-coverage, teamcity-8.0

We're configuring build steps in TeamCity. Since we have huge problems with test coverage reports (they were there and then inexplainably vanished), we're trying to find a work-trough (asking and bouting a question directly related to our issue yielded very cold response).

Please note that I'm not looking for **an opinion** but rather a technical knowledge base to support (or kill) the choice of ours. And yes, I've checked the build logs - these are posted in the other thread. This question is about the (in?)sanity of trying an alternative approach.   :)

1. Is it recommended to run a build step for test and then another build step for test coverage?
2. Does it even makes sense to run these in separate build steps?!
3. What gains and disadvantages are there to running coverage bundled with/separately from the tests themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Test coverage reports are generated during unit test runs.  Unless your problem is with reading generated reports, it doesn't make sense to "run them in separate build steps".  Test coverage tells you what parts of your code were run WHILE the tests were running- I don't see how they could be independent.

It may make more sense to ask for help with the test coverage reports no longer being generated...

Comment: I did. [Right here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458639/how-to-trouble-shoot-missing-test-coverage-in-teamcity) I got very limited response.   :(